# Integrate Cypress in PR build

Tags: jenkins, devops, cypress

I have an existing cypress docker image. I want to integrate it in existing docker file where PR build have to pass cypress test. give me any idea how I will I do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want integrate cypress test(we have cypress docker image) into our existing Jenkins pipeline(all PR should pass the cypress test before merge)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a github workflow and cypress itself provide its [github action](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action), you can write a job for it and provide when it wants to run the workflow job (on push/Prlabel) . Cypress tests then run on the PR and will create a job summary on the summary page. (See to the link and it provides examples how to use )